# How can we derive ruler postulate from Hilbert's axioms?

Tags: geometry, foundations, axiomatic-geometry

Ruler postulate:

> For every pair of points $P$ and $Q$ there exists a real number PQ, called the distance from $P$ to $Q$. For each line $l$ there is a one-to-one correspondence from $l$ to $R$ such that if $P$ and $Q$ are points on the line that correspond to the real numbers $x$ and $y$, respectively, then $PQ=|x−y|$.

Its implications:

> (1) There are infinitely many points lying on a line segment. *(provable utilizing axioms of incidence and axioms of order)*
>
> (2) There is a one-to-one correspondence between real numbers and points on a line.
>
> (3) Two distinct points determine exactly one line. *(provable utilizing axiom I.1 and axiom I.2)*
>
> (4) Definition of distance
>
> (5) $PQ=|x−y|$

How can we derive (2), (4) and (5)?

Comment: (4) was done by Eudoxus many centuries ago, but Hilbert chose another way (see his chapter III) to avoid using Archimedes' axiom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The definition of distance and how to prove the ruler postulate in Euclidean geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317470/the-definition-of-distance-and-how-to-prove-the-ruler-postulate-in-euclidean-geo)